# Replacing OOP code by only functions file (SP instead OOP)

Tags: java, jsp, oop

I'm not Java expert but I'm curious. Suppose that I have this:

```
String StringRepeater(String s, Qty q) {
    String S = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<q;i++) {
        S +=s;
    }
    return S;
}

boolean MyComp(int a, int b) {
    return (a<b);
}
```

I want to replace the before code by respective Java code. I don't want to use static class.

It's possible to implement it, but not using a static class/singleton, I read that Java allows to implement this code (different to OOP) in **structured programming** maybe (Wikipedia).

Comment: Out of curiosity what exactly is `String StringRepeater(..)`? I know it's a method because you have the return type. The lack of `private`/`public` is confusing me a bit.

Comment: Private/Public belongs to OOP Concepts, I want to implement this without class, the function (not methods) are example of functions that to do something...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have side effects or mutable state then there's nothing wrong with having a static method. See the java.lang.Math class for an example.

This might look like:

```
public final class Util { // final disallows inheritance

    private Util() {} // making constructor private disallows instantiating this

    public static String repeat(String s, int times) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            builder.append(s);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

This is the usual non-OO procedural approach. Java doesn't have a way to create independent functions that don't belong to a class.

You could take this static method and create an EL function for it (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6396886/217324)). and that would give you a function that you could call in the JSP. Or you could call the method in a controller and populate a request attribute with the returned value.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the opposite of what is being asked? *"but not using a static class/singleton"*

Comment: @Bart: hard to say, the question could be clearer. the OP seems to want a non-OOP, "structured programming" way of creating a function he can call from his jsp. the answer explains he can't do without a class, and suggests creating an EL function that would let him create the function he wants. so I think it addresses what he needs.

Answer (score 0):

*It's possible to implement it, but not using a static class/singleton, I read that Java allows to implement this code (different to OOP) in structured programming maybe(Wikipedia).*

Another way of implementing *"structural programing"* in java is using JNI. Using JNI you can communicate java applications with modules written in another languages (C, C++, Python, Javascript...). It's complicated but some times is necessary.

Take a look to these links:

http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html

[Can I call Java from Node.js via JNI and how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729013/can-i-call-java-from-node-js-via-jni-and-how)

Regards,