# Is there a way to work with Java SE jars in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, jar

I have on one side an API which is written in Java and on the other side an Client which is written in javascript. Is there a way to use this API maybe together with the other Java-SE jars in Javascript, perhaps in Webstorm?

Thanks for all helps.

Comment: Expose the API with REST

Comment: Still j2se will not be able to call it while crossDomain issue you can use jsonp for making it usable for desktop apps or use simple httpReq to get result

Comment: @anshu or set cors headers ... Besides that js and Rest can run on the same host / port

Comment: I think cors headers would work only for calls by server(http origin)... from desktop app that would be request by TCP IP.....correct  me: may be i could wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server side (Java) need to pushlish RESTful API. So client side (Javascript) can use these API.

You can check out these links to more information about RESTful: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer),
[restapitutorial](http://www.restapitutorial.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about which kind of Client? It will be a regular browser client? If so, there is no way to do it unless to make server calls using post, rest, whatever you want. 
If your client is written in node.js or jrunscript you have some tricks to do it, see these links: [node-java module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729013/can-i-call-java-from-node-js-via-jni-and-how) and [jrunscript](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things9/).

Regards