# Convert "wmf" image format in html tag to "png" format - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, png, image-conversion, wmf

I am working in a nodejs based project which requires converting "wmf" to "png" format. Since browsers don't support "wmf" format. So, I would need to write code to convert it into equivalent "png" format **img tag** in nodejs.
For instance, image is currently represented as:

`<img src="data:image/x-wmf;base64,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" />`

Also, the client server is Linux based. So "wmf2png" npm package won't work.
Since image is inline and not stored as a separate "*.wmf" file, npm package like "libwmf" does not seem to work.

So is there any way I could convert images like this and represent in equivalent form?

Comment: I think the best solution would be to Node converting `wmf` to `png` and sending the `png` to client. You can see the link attached by @Teemu

Comment: @Teemu - Server is Linux based. So "wmf2png" won't work.

Comment: Hi @VedangBamnote, did you try libwmf ?

Comment: Hi @salesh, i had seen libwmf. In my case image is inline so this would not work either.

Comment: @VedangBamnote did you consider maybe us external services? :/

Comment: I would use [node-java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9352818/2066598) and render it via [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/components/slideshow/ppt-wmf-emf-renderer.html). Either write your own wrapper or use PPTX2PNG or ask at the POI mailing list and I'd provide you the wrapper then.